# how to copy some specific .jpg files to another directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I want to copy some specific jpg files to another directory and I don't understand why it doesn't work? I have a lot of image and want to sort on certain categories for the moment only those that have the beginning name of 15_0_xxx.jpg respectively 15_1_xxx.jpg

```
import cv2

import sys
import os
import shutil 
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = "c:/Users/Harum/Desktop/make dir/"
file_names = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

print(str(len(file_names))+ ' images loaded')

cont_M =0
cont_F =0
m_age = "c:/Users/Harum/Desktop/make dir/M_15/"
f_age = "c:/Users/Harum/Desktop/make dir/F_15/"

input_m = []
input_mS =[]
input_fS =[]
input_f = []

def getZeros(number):
    if(number > 10 and number <100):
        return "0"
    if(number < 10):
        return "00"
    else:
        return ""

for i, file in enumerate(file_names):
    if file_names[i][0] == "15_0":
        cont_M +=1
        image = cv2.imread(mypath+file)
        input_m.append(image)
        input_mS.append(0)
        zeros = getZeros(cont_M)
        cv2.imwrite(m_age +"m_age"+str(zeros)+ str(cont_M)+ ".jpg",image)

    if file_names[i][0] == "15_1":
        cont_F +=1
        image = cv2.imread(mypath+file)
        input_f.append(image)
        input_fs.append(1)
        cv2.imwrite(f_age+"F_age"+str(zeros)+ str(cont_M)+ ".jpg",image)
```

`

Comment: Please add a proper description of the problem!

Comment: This would be *so much easier* if you used pathlib with a glob...

Comment: Why use OpenCV for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** forgot the copying part. You can use shutil for that

You would do better with glob and os:

```
from shutil import copyfile
import glob
import os

mypath = "c:/Users/Harum/Desktop/make dir/"
destination_path = "c:/Users/Harum/Desktop/copy/"
# using fstrings to add wildcard character to consider all files. You could add a
## file extension after, as in f"{mypath}15_*.jpg"
file_names = glob.glob(f"{mypath}15_*")

# skip the middle to the ifs
# (...)

# removed the enumerate as it doesn't seems like you're using the positional list index

for file in file_names:
    # getting only the filename (with extension)
    file_name = os.path.basename(file)

    # using the str().startswith() to check True or False
    if file_name.startswith("15_0"):
        cont_M +=1
        copyfile(file, f"{destination_path}{file_name}")
        # (...)

    elif file_name.startswith("15_1"):
        cont_F +=1
        copyfile(file, f"{destination_path}{file_name}")
        #(...)
```

Comment: Intentional, I just copied the way the OP did... but yeah.. seems unnecessary, will edit, cheers!

Comment: If you are going to glob, might as well do `f"{mypath}15_*"` just to cut down on the files returned.

Comment: @Joey, you sure? check both `if file_names[i][0]` at OP's question

Comment: @Joey hey Joe, I didn't say anywhere that there are syntax errors at OP's. You said `the OP has no double if in his code example` which I just replied that there is 2 "if file_names" which should be if /else as you suggested in your first comment.

Comment: @mrbTT Sorry, it was a misunderstanding. I just wanted to point out the error in the last `if` statement in your code. You wrote `elif if file_name.startswith("15_1")`.

Comment: nice catch! Thank you =)